# How can i call async method like a synch method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am using node.js and mongoDB with promises.js. I have to call an async method in promise variable but i can not make an another than(). Because it is in loop. the code is like:

```
collection1.find({'key': 'value'})
            .then(function(matches){
               //loop starts
                matches.forEach(function(match){
                    var currentUser = collection2.find({"_id" : match._user})
                    console.log(currentUser); //undefined
                })
})
```

As you can see currentUser is an undefined variable. How can i fix that?

Comment: shouldn't currentUser be a promise?

Comment: Also, wouldn't it be better to collect a list of id's you want to pull and pull them all in one trip?

Comment: (which would coincidentally solve your problem and be more performant)

Comment: you need to put the log in a `.then` off of the inner find(), there's no reason a loop precludes use of promises...

Comment: If you want help with your overall problem, you need to describe the overall problem including your loop and what you're trying to accomplish in your loop.  There are lots of different ways to handle a sequence of async operations that might be traditionally done in a loop, but how to best approach them depends upon the description of the overall problem.  Based on your title, the answer is that you **CANNOT** call an async method like a sync method.  You must adapt the tools and programming methods that you use.  What to do instead, needs more description of your problem.

Comment: Do you need to run your `matches` loop in sequence, one after another?  Or can  you run all the matches in parallel and just coordinate the result at that end of all the requests?  What exactly to you want to do with the results when all the requests are done?

Comment: As this question stands, it is lacking sufficient information to make a concrete suggestion on how this problem should be solved.  Please fix the question to clarify exactly what you're trying to accomplish in your loop..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`deep-populate`](https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate)

`async` could also work:

```
function processMatch(match, cb) {
  collection2.findOne({"_id":match._user}).then(function(user) {
    cb(null, user);
  });
}
collection1.find({'key':'value'})
  .then(function(matches) {
    var async = require('async');
    async.mapLimit(results.results, NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL_REQUEST, processMatch, function(err, users) {
      users.forEach(function(currentUser) {
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: It is customary to justify negative voting with comments so the answer can be ameliorated...

Comment: since when is it customary to justify voting? It is customary to provide feedback via comments, but that doesn't have anything to do with voting.

Comment: replace "customary" with "beneficial" or "polite"

Comment: @KevinB - Failure to attach any comment to a downvote is analogous to putting a kid on timeout without telling them why they're being punished.  It's very unlikely to influence future behavior which is one huge aspect of negative feedback.  Instead, it just makes everyone mad and doesn't really accomplish much.    So, "good citizens" here at stack overflow choose to "teach" when adding a downvote so the recipient can learn and the community benefits.  I've never seen a downvote that couldn't be described in 1-2 targeted sentences.

Comment: Did not mean to pontificate, just was puzzled and wanted to improve... Even Stackoverflow suggests it when you click the down arrow...

@dandavis agreed